# Only null values in BigQuery after changes to new schema when importing from Firebase Analytics

Tags: google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

A while back we got an email from Google saying they would move all our Firebase Analytics data in BigQuery to a new table and a new schema. Fair enough.

A couple of days ago, the change was made. But the problem now is that we only see null events in our `<project>:analytics_xxxxx_.events_<date>` table. The events are correct in the intraday table, but for the last three days we only have null values in the events table. Anyone else seen this? Did we do something wrong or is it a bug with Google BigQuery?

[image]

Comment: Same for me. Only null values.

Comment: @kimHafr, how did you obtain the "Firebase Analytics Property ID" that the sh scripts requires (PROPERTY_ID). I've not been able to find it in my Firebase settings.

Comment: In the firebase dashboard for your app - Select Dashboard in the Analytics section. Then you should see a Analytics Settings button in the upper right corner. Press that and you will find a Property id in the upper right corner

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/51259455/132438, for a handy migration script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that you used the script they sent you for importing from Firebase. This is a known issue, and in some cases the script breaks the schema and that's probably why you are getting those null values.

I would recommend to reach Firebase Support [[1]](https://firebase.google.com/support/) and they will help you solve this.

EDIT: I saw this other question posted and answered by a Googler that may be of help [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51259454/firebase-bigquery-schema-migration-move-into-a-partitioned-table)

Comment: Could be that was the problem, I reached out to Firebase Support, and the schema was fixed 